# Qt QMessageBox - closes application instead of just message box

Tags: qt, qmessagebox

have created a QMessageBox that appears when I press a 'Start' button on my application.

When either button is pressed (Ok or Cancel) - I want the message box to close - but the application to remain open.

Unfortunately, when I hit Ok or Cancel the whole application closes. Any tips?

J

Here's my code:

```
  Main.cpp:

    #include "openingdialog.h"
    #include <QApplication>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        Dialog w;
        w.show();

        return a.exec();
    }

Opening Dialog:

patientsetup::patientsetup(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::patientsetup)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
     connect(ui->okButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(confirmButtonClicked()));
     connect(ui->ACSMode, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(ACSButtonClicked()));
     connect(ui->PromptMode, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(PMPSAIButtonClicked()));
     connect(ui->FullMode, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(PMPSFullbuttonClicked()));
}

void patientsetup::PMPSAIButtonClicked()
{
direct = new pmps_f(this);
        direct->setData(patient, ui->Weight->value(), ui->Height->value(), lbmvalue, bsavalue, gender);
        direct->show();
}

pmps_f MainWindow    

           pmps_f::pmps_f(QWidget *parent) :
            QMainWindow(parent),
            ui(new Ui::pmps_f)
        {
            ui->setupUi(this);
            connect(ui->startbutton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(start()));
        }

             void pmps_f::start()
            {
                QMessageBox msgBox;
                msgBox.setText("Pressing continue will start the process with the process");
                msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok | QMessageBox::Cancel);
                msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Cancel);
                int ret = msgBox.exec();
                switch(ret) {
                    case QMessageBox::Ok:
                    msgBox.close();
                    break;
                case QMessageBox::Cancel:
                    msgBox.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Full code:

```
pmps_f::pmps_f(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::pmps_f)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->startbutton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(start()));
}

pmps_f::~pmps_f()
{
    delete ui;
}

//public function that pulls the Patient data from the patientsetup.ui interface
void pmps_f::setData(const QString &fileName, const double &weightValue, const double &heightValue, const double &lbmValue, const double &bsaValue, const QString &genderName)
{
    ui->file->setText(fileName);
    ui->weight->setText(QString::number(weightValue));
    ui->height->setText(QString::number(heightValue));
    ui->lbm->setText(QString::number(lbmValue));
    ui->bsa->setText(QString::number(bsaValue));
    ui->gender->setText(genderName);
}

//Sedation start confirmation check
void pmps_f::start()
{
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Pressing continue will start the sedation process");
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok | QMessageBox::Cancel);
    msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Cancel);
    int ret = msgBox.exec();
    switch(ret) {
       case QMessageBox::Ok:
       break;
      case QMessageBox::Cancel:
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `pmps_f` and how do you call its `start()` function?

Comment: Also does you application have other windows opened?

Comment: It is a QWidget, start() is called by pushing a button called Start...

Comment: QMainWindow is opened when the QMessageBox is called.

Comment: Then we need to see more code after start() is called (or more code that is inside start function, i assume that because you don't set any state, at least what button was clicked) 

Also, have you tried running with a debugger attached? The application most likely crashes.

Comment: This is all of the code of the start() function.

Comment: Here is the pmps_f setup:

Comment: pmps_f::pmps_f(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::pmps_f)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->startbutton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(start()));
}

Comment: Debugger shows no errors - just a message saying 'exited with code 0'

Comment: Try without calling close() for the msgBox, comment or delete the calls: _msgBox.close();_ (in both cases of the switch) when you reach that code the message box is closed anyway. This should not close the main window, but maybe it's a bug.

Comment: Tried with msgBox.close() removed - still closing entire application!

Comment: What platform are you targeting? Qt version?

Comment: @JamesSprinks, try to call `setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false)` on your `QApplication`.

Comment: Windows, QT Creator 4.4.1, based on Qt 5.9.2...

Comment: setQuitOnLAstWindowClosed(false) had no affect...

Comment: Then definitely you have a crash. Can you post more code?

Comment: That's all the code part from main.cpp. which looks like:

Comment: #include "openingdialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

Comment: How/where pmps_f instance is created? Post that code too

Comment: Created from previous window:

Comment: direct = new pmps_f(this);
      
        direct->show();

Comment: Post the code for the Dialog (constructor, connections, function/slot that creates the pmps_f and code that runs after start() is executed) something is closing the dialog, or there is a crash.

Comment: As I said this is the total code that runs after start is executed.

Comment: 'patientsetup::patientsetup(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::patientsetup)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
     connect(ui->okButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(confirmButtonClicked()));
     connect(ui->ACSMode, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(ACSButtonClicked()));
     connect(ui->PromptMode, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(PMPSAIButtonClicked()));
     connect(ui->FullMode, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(PMPSFullbuttonClicked()));
}

Comment: void patientsetup::PMPSFullbuttonClicked()

Comment: direct = new pmps_f(this);
        direct->show();

Comment: Your message-box doesn't close the main-window(s), somewhere else you close it, or you crash the application. Use the debugger or post your code or a complete-compilable example that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Entire code now above.

Comment: Debugger shows no errors - and I do not close the main windows in my code anywhere...

Comment: This really needs an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Make an example that reproduces the problem with minimal amount of code (remove all the irrelevant stuff, only keep the stuff that is needed to reproduce the problem), and put it in a single file that we can copy and compile.

Comment: See below... Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to the solve the problem using:

setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);

However - now the program does not quit properly when the window 'x' button is pushed...

Can anyone help?

Comment: any python approach? cause this is the closest thing I found

Comment: nevermind, i found it, self.app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)